# Unity is smoothing my low poly models, how do I control this?

Tags: unity, blender

I started a new universal pipeline project and have modelled a really quick low poly character in blender. It stays quite blocky in blender, but when dropped into the unity project its really highly smoothed? I quite like it, but would like to control it if necessary i.e if I want to go back to the blocky models, how do I do so? And where are the settings to play around with it.

Cheers,

[image: Blender version]

[image: Unity version]

Comment: I don't have much Unity 3D experience, but the issue might be that it's shaded smooth instead of shaded flat. Try following [this video](https://www.lmhpoly.com/tutorials/how-to-change-object-shading-in-unity).

Comment: Usually whether a face is shaded smooth or hard is decided in Blender. But the default in Blender is hard, so most beginners in Blender have the opposite problem.

Comment: Usually despite being shaded flat in the Blender project, the export settings (at least for FBX) will actually try and shade it smooth, I'd definitely check the Blender export settings, as well as origin points/axis.

Comment: [We have some existing Q&A about achieving flat shading in Unity](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+flat+shading)